# python copy file with meta data, shutil vs manually opening and writing a duplicate file

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying

According to http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html using these methods will not copy over meta-data including ownership, ACL's, and resource forks. Would opening the file using the basic file reading methods and write it back to a duplicate file, line for line, keep the files meta-data intact? My guess is yes. Would the destination disk have to be the same format as the source to keep things intact? My guess is no. 
I browsed around and didn't see anything specific to this. I want to basically back up 3 different computers, running different OS's, to one central location using python. It's integral that the files being copied are identical as if I could replace the originals and see no differences. Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue in that I have to preserve owner and group information on unix filesystems.  These are just integers, but shutil.copy2 does not preserve them.  Although you are copying across systems, you could just modify the code to store the metadata somewhere and then apply it after you are done the copy.

```
import os
import shutil
import stat

def CopyMinusP(src, dest):
  file_stat = os.stat(src)
  owner = file_stat[stat.ST_UID]
  group = file_stat[stat.ST_GID]
  print "Owner: %d  Group: %d" % (owner, group)  # for diagnostics
  shutil.copy2(src, dest)
  os.chown(dest, owner, group)
```

Comment: this is a fantastic idea

Answer (score 0):

No, simply opening the source file for reading and the destination file for writing would not copy the metadata.  How should the OS know it should?  Moreover, different filesystems support different metadata, and there is no filesytem-independent way to copy all metadata.  When copying between different filesystems, it is often impossible to preserve metadata.  How should a resource fork be preserved when copying to a FAT file system?  There is simply no such thing on FAT. So both your guesses are wrong.

You should use a good backup solution instead that fully supports all the filesystems you use.

Comment: I see what you're saying, is meta-data then not stored within the file itself? I would not expect it to be useful if a HFS+ file was stored on a Fat32 partition, but I also wouldn't think the file would be destroyed either; this is in regards to manually writing the data to disk.

Comment: @scape: No, metadata is not stored within the file.  Simply create an empty file and call `open("empty_file").read()` in the interactive Python interpreter.  This will show the full file contents – the empty string.  No metadata.

Comment: @scape: What do you mean by "manually writing the data to disk"?  Using a magnetised pin?

Comment: Hah no, I mean in terms of opening and writing the file contents back to the disk as opposed to using a method such as shutil's copy. I'll have to read up a bit on how metadata is stored on the drive then, thanks!